# Exception handling in python using class

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have doubt in python exception. 
Below code is taken from python document and I am confuse at one point. If any one can help, will be thankful.
Here this codes gives output as:

> B C D

```
class B(Exception):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except D:
        print("D")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except B:
        print("B")
```

If I change except part of code like below code:
output will be :

> B B B

```
class B(Exception):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except B:
        print("B")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except D:
        print("D")
```

When I run this code without try block as shown below:

```
class B(Exception):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    raise cls()
```

Here output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/885710/Documents/PY/ErrorHandling.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise cls()
B
```

Similary for below code:

```
class B(Exception):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass
for cls in [C,B, D]:
    raise cls()
```

Output is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/885710/Documents/PY/ErrorHandling.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise cls()
C
```

I confused because, if I run this code separately then it gives output as B or C or D
then why in my second code snippet it is giving output as

```
B
B
B
```

even though except is define for all 3 Class B, C, D

Comment: *C* **is** *B*, and *D* **is** *C* (which in turn is *B*), so (transitively) *D* **is** *B* (this is what inheritance is all about). The order that you are trying to handle exceptions **is** important (in this case). Probably you should extend all of your classes from ***Exception*** (instead of one from another - like you do now), and you'd get the behavior you desire in your 2nd snippet (without changing the other scenario(s)). `class C(Exception):`, `class D(Exception):`.

Comment: Probably you should extend all of your classes from Exception>> can u please explain with example?

Comment: If D is C and C is B hence D is B, then why it print B,C,D in first snippet and B,B,B in second. Still didnt get the point

Comment: Because **is** is **one way only**: *C* **is** *B*, but *B* **is not** *C*.

Comment: Ok Thank u.. got it.

Answer (score 2):

[Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) says:

> A class in an except clause is compatible with an exception if it is
>   the same class or a base class

Therefore the given code:

```
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except D:
        print("D")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except B:
        print("B")
```

Can be simplified into the following:

```
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    foo = cls()
    if isinstance(foo, D):
        print("D")
    elif isinstance(foo, C):
        print("C")
    elif isinstance(foo, B):
        print("B")
```

Then your modification would be turned into:

```
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    foo = cls()
    if isinstance(foo, B):
        print("B")
    elif isinstance(foo, C):
        print("C")
    elif isinstance(foo, D):
        print("D")
```

So regardless whether `foo` is instance of `B`, `C` or `D` it will fulfil the first case, because `isinstance` yields `True` for instances of a subclass too.

Comment: Thanx for adding up one more explanation. Great help!

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` is the super class of `C` and `D` your second version will always use the first `except` block for `B`. Because the Python runtime will search for a matching `except` block from top to bottom. An `except` block is matching if the exception is an instance of the class in the `except` block. If you throw an instance `C` for instance this block will match because `C()` is (also) an instance of `B`.

As a rule of thumb the `except` statements must decrease from the most specific condition to the most general condition, e. g.:

```
try:
    throw ...
except D: # the most specific class
    print("D")
except C: # is more specific than B but less than D
    print("C")
except B: # the most general class in your hierarchy
    print("B")
except BaseException as e: the most general exception class
    print(e.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank u so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand the class hierarchy involved in this code sample

```
class B(Exception):
    pass
class C(B):
    pass
class D(C):
    pass
```

B -> Base class

C -> inherits from B

D -> inherits from C and C -> inherits from B

thus D -> inherits from B and C

**A try statement may have more than one except clause for different exceptions. But at most one except clause will be executed**

Unless you are catching the raised the exception then base class is given the priority to be caught. i.e when exception classes are inherited then the priority in the `except` is given to the BASE class (in your code it's class `B`).

Now the first case :

```
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except D:
        print("D")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except B:
        print("B")
```

`Iteration 1` : 
  element : B

First control checks the `except D` as it's not a base class nor the matching class to the raised one then control will move to `except C` and at last it will execute `except B`, thus prints `B`.

`Iteration 2` : 
  element : C

First control checks the `except D` as it's not a base class nor the matching class to the raised one then control will move to `except C` and will execute `except C`, thus prints `C`

`Iteration 3` : 
  element : D

First control checks the `except D` as it's a matching class then control will 
 execute `except D`, thus prints `D`

Now consider Second case :

```
for cls in [B, C, D]:
    try:
        raise cls()
    except B:
        print("B")
    except C:
        print("C")
    except D:
        print("D")
```

Here `B` is the base class for classes `C` and `D` so when you write `except B` at the top of except stack then the control does not go to subsequent `except C` and `except D`. So it prints output as `B` for each iteration of for loop.